# angular testing Error: Can't resolve all parameters for WelcomeComponent: (?)

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I copied the official website to my project below, but when running karma test appeared in this error.
Does anyone know why this is it?
 Error: Can't resolve all parameters for WelcomeComponent: (?).
            at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (karma-shim.js:16768:19) [ProxyZone]

```html
//welcome.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from "./user.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome',
  template: '<h3 class="welcome" ><i>{{welcome}}</i></h3>'
})
export class WelcomeComponent  implements OnInit {
  welcome = '-- not initialized yet --';
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.welcome = this.userService.isLoggedIn ?
      'Welcome, ' + this.userService.user.name :
      'Please log in.';
  }
}
```

```html
//welcome.component.spec.ts
describe('WelcomeComponent', () => {

  let comp: WelcomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WelcomeComponent>;
  let componentUserService: UserService; // the actually injected service
  let userService: UserService; // the TestBed injected service
  let de: DebugElement;  // the DebugElement with the welcome message
  let el: HTMLElement; // the DOM element with the welcome message

  let userServiceStub: {
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    user: { name: string}
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    // stub UserService for test purposes
    userServiceStub = {
      isLoggedIn: true,
      user: { name: 'Test User'}
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declarations: [ WelcomeComponent ],
       providers:    [ {provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceStub } ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
    comp    = fixture.componentInstance;

    // UserService actually injected into the component
    userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);
    componentUserService = userService;
    // UserService from the root injector
    userService = TestBed.get(UserService);

    //  get the "welcome" element by CSS selector (e.g., by class name)
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.welcome'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
  });

  it('should welcome the user', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const content = el.textContent;
    expect(content).toContain('Welcome', '"Welcome ..."');
    expect(content).toContain('Test User', 'expected name');
  });

  it('should welcome "Bubba"', () => {
    userService.user.name = 'Bubba'; // welcome message hasn't been shown yet
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.textContent).toContain('Bubba');
  });

  it('should request login if not logged in', () => {
    userService.isLoggedIn = false; // welcome message hasn't been shown yet
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const content = el.textContent;
    expect(content).not.toContain('Welcome', 'not welcomed');
    expect(content).toMatch(/log in/i, '"log in"');
  });

  it('should inject the component\'s UserService instance',
    inject([UserService], (service: UserService) => {
    expect(service).toBe(componentUserService);
  }));

  it('TestBed and Component UserService should be the same', () => {
    expect(userService === componentUserService).toBe(true);
  });

  it('stub object and injected UserService should not be the same', () => {
    expect(userServiceStub === userService).toBe(false);

    // Changing the stub object has no effect on the injected service
    userServiceStub.isLoggedIn = false;
    expect(userService.isLoggedIn).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you pelase add your testing module configurations? looks like you're missing UserService in your testing module providers.

Comment: import { ComponentFixture, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }                                from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }                      from '@angular/core';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';
import {UserService} from "./user.service";

Comment: Do you mean test.module.ts?I've add the UserService in it's providers.but cought the same error too.And i have just import the UserService into the welcome.component.spec.ts

Comment: @W.Wei did you ever resolve this? I'm also trying to follow https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-a-dependency but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error in my project, but for me the reason was that one service could not be injected due to circular dependencies - resolving the circular dependencies solved the injection error for me.